# .innerHTML does not update the page - AJAX

Tags: ajax, html-select

Below, I have a java script function (named stateChange) which is expected to update the content of an HTML  selection list (Please see the code section marked as HERE below). I have verified that the server returns the new data properly by writing some alert statements (i.e. xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() { alert(xmlHttp.responseText); }).

Based on these alert statements in the function, I noticed that the line

```
      document.getElementById("dgpids").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
```

is not executed at all, so the page is not updated with the new data from the server.

Can someone tell me what I am missing here in the function stateChange below? Why do you think the page is not updated with new data? Thanks.

```
     <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
     <%@page import="com.pm.dao.VirtualConfigTableDAO;" %>
     <%@page import="com.pm.entity.VirtualConfigEntity;" %>
     <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>DAE PM Counters</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
        var xmlHttp              
        function stateChange(){                                  
            if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
                **//!!!!!! HERE !!!!!**
                //FOLLOWING LINE works                    
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() { alert(xmlHttp.responseText); }
                //I cannot update the list named dgpids below.
                //The content of the response text coming from the server is correct.
                //But the following line does not update the page. Do you know why???
                document.getElementById("dgpids").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;   

                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() { alert('Got here2!'); }                                       
            }                                  
        }

        function showState(str){
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
                xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject){
                xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            if (xmlHttp==null){
                alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
                return;
            } 
            var url="dgp.jsp";
            url +="?id=" +str;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }


    </script> 

</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="me">
        <select size="13" name="D1"  multiple="no" onChange="checkData()">             
            <option value="1">CommonCounters(vDaeId)</option>
            <option value="2">DgpCommonCounters(dgpId, vDaeId)</option>
            <option value="3">SystemCommonCounters()</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2"></p>        
        <br/>

        <%
            VirtualConfigTableDAO dao = new VirtualConfigTableDAO();
            List<VirtualConfigEntity> vList = dao.getEntireVirtualConfigList();
        %>

        <select size="2" name="D2"  multiple="no" onChange="if (this.selectedIndex != -1) showState(this.value);" onclick="showState(this.value);">   
            <%
                for (VirtualConfigEntity entity : vList) {
            %>                              
            <option value="<%=String.valueOf(entity.getId())%>"> <%=String.valueOf(entity.getVirtualId())%></option>
            <%}%> 
        </select>


        <br/>
        <br/>
        <select name="dgpids" >  
            <option value='-1'></option>  
        </select>


    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You could take a look at this, to see how you can update a select list with javascript:
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061020095758AAq8Azk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an element with an id of `dgpids`.

I think you meant to give the select an id but I'm not sure a select would allow `innerHTML`. You may be better wrapping the select in a `div` and updating your server code to return the full select html which can be inserted into the div.

Something like in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CU5Sp/3/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ya that solved the issue. Sorry, should have been more careful. Thanks.